# How to avoid delay in output stream pipe

Tags: pipe

While i pipe **nethogs** it takes too much delay for the output ( About 5-200 sec instead of 1 sec  depend on pipe,cmd etc).
Nethogs print output in every second.

For the sake of simplicity consider the following command ( it takes abt 5 sec )

`sudo nethogs ppp0 | grep e | grep e |grep c`

I belive it due to the buffering in pipe.

How can i avoid the delay (In **general** or in the **case of nethogs**)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. It can be done simply using perl.

```
perl -le 'open(P," top  |");  $|=1; while(<P>){ print }'
```

Take the **example** of

```
top | grep i | grep id
perl -le 'open(P," top  |");  $|=1; while(<P>){ print "------","$_"; }' | grep i | grep id
```

For `nethogs`

```
perl -le 'open(P,"sudo nethogs ppp0 |");  $|=1; while(<P>){ print "------","$_"; }' |  grep e | grep e |grep c
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `stdbuf` or `unbuffer` commands. I'm [on a related situation](https://askubuntu.com/q/1122816/349837)