# CLI line buffer: How to pipe to grep an output stream?

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe, sox

I have this command (for [pomodoros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique)):

```
play -n synth 25:00 pinknoise
```

I don't want to silent completely the output (`-q` option), just the header (`grep` don't work).

Normal output:

```
File Size: 94.3T     
 Encoding: n/a           
 Channels: 1 @ 32-bit   
Samplerate: 48000Hz      
Replaygain: off         
 Duration: unknown      

In:0.00% 00:00:01.02 [00:00:00.00] Out:49.2k [======|======] Hd:1.3 Clip:0
```

Desire filtered output: `01.02` (this number is updated, like in a cURL or `pv` progress bar)

How can I grep just that part of the output?

So far:

- For some reason the output is sent to stderr, like with "Permission denied" from `find`. An easy way to test is to add at the end `2> /dev/null`.

  Maybe the reason why sox/play output to stderr is because it supports writing the output to standard output (stdout) using the special filename `-` (see [sox man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox)).
- But `|& grep "^In"` won't work. Using `|& tee log.txt` it seems uses the [delete character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) to update the last line.

  I tried [`grep --line-buffered`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html#options), [`unbuffer`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/expect_unbuffer.1.html) and [`stdbuf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/stdbuf.1.html) (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154536/4970442) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139997/209677)) with some great progress:

  ```
    play -n synth 25:00 pinknoise  2>&1 | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9] '
  ```

That's very close!

Is possible to get only just one updated line like was on the original output? Maybe [like this loop with `echo -ne`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297780/4970442).

I'm not sure why something like  `| grep --line-buffered .` doesn't work, neither removing trailing newline: `| tr -d '\n'`. I need something like `tail -f -n 1`.

Answer (score 4):

You can grep the output if you pipe stderr as well, e.g.:

```
$ play -n synth 25:00 pinknoise |& grep File
 File Size: 2.52G
```

From [*Pipelines* section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) of GNU Bash manual:

> If ‘`|&`’ is used, *command1*’s standard error, in addition to its
>   standard output, is connected to *command2*’s standard input through
>   the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of
>   the standard error to the standard output is performed after any
>   redirections specified by the command.

However, this will not work for the progress line: CLI commands usually test whether the output is to a terminal and discard updated output if it isn’t. We need a hacky workaround to get around that. First redirect the full output to a file:

```
play -n synth 25:00 pinknoise &>sox.log
```

This blocks the current terminal and you can *not* just send it to the background because then it discards the progress line again. So to get this line, open a second terminal in the same directory and process the file, e.g.:

```
$ grep In sox.log
In:0.00% 00:00:03.24 [00:00:00.00] Out:156k  [======|======] Hd:0.8 Clip:0
$ tail -n+10 sox.log; echo
In:0.00% 00:00:10.24 [00:00:00.00] Out:492k  [!=====|=====!] Hd:1.7 Clip:0
```

The advantage of using `tail` is that you also get the `Aborted.` line when the `play` exited:

```
$ tail -n+10 sox.log;echo
In:0.00% 00:00:12.80 [00:00:00.00] Out:614k  [======|======] Hd:0.7 Clip:0    
Aborted.
```

Comment: Sorry, this was near but doesn't really work for what I want: get rid of the header so I can only have the line starting with "In:", the one that is updated. I don't know why `|& grep "^In"` doesn't work.

Comment: @PabloBianchi Oh I’m sorry, I misunderstood your question. Could you edit and clarify, maybe giving an example for the desired output?

Comment: I added an example of the desired output. Using `stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n'` I'm almost there! Are you sure is necessary to process a file on other terminal? It seems it have something to do with the output buffers.